# Check type of generic Combine Publisher Output Swift

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have a function which access data from my server. The server can either return a JSON object of type `Player`:

```
{"id":"6B38EF76-6BBC-4423-BCB6-FD9F9B5E7A6F","ign":"Shard","region":"eu","rating":1000}
```

or of type `Standard Response`:

```
{"statusCode":4,"description":"Invalid Arguments"}
```

I have a function with the following pattern:

```
fetch<T: Decodable>(from endpoint: Endpoint) -> AnyPublisher<T, DatabaseError>
```

This function access the server via a data task publisher and decodes the result into a generic T using combine's built in decode operator:

```
.decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

I have the two types of response I showed above modelled as structs with the relevant coding keys etc and this part of the code works fine.

I use the fetch function inside a different function which passes it the relevant endpoint

```
func getPlayerDetails(of id: UUID) -> AnyPublisher<Player, DatabaseError> {
    return fetch(from: .getDetails(of: id, isTeam: false))
}
```

As you can see this function returns the publisher with `Player` as the output. My question is how can I check the generic output of `fetch(from:)` and if it is a player object, pass that through, and if not return my custom error `DatabaseError`?

Thanks

Comment: If I understood your question, that would just happen. Inside `getPlayerDetails`, the compiler would infer the generic type `T` of `fetch` to be `Player`, and return the `AnyPublisher<Player, DatabaseError>` result. If the publisher is successful, you'd get a `Player` instance; if not - a `DatabaseError` failure

Comment: Ah okay, so can I just use .mapError to specify what type of DatabaseError it should be? Because DatabaseError is an enum with a few cases depending on the type of error

Comment: Presumably, `.fetch` would return the correct error, but you could also `.mapError` separately inside `getPlayerDetails`. Depends on what you need to return and where to make that determination

Comment: Okay thanks for your help I'll have a look and write up my final answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out how I to solve my problem, this doesn't really answer the original question however [this](https://forums.swift.org/t/combine-try-to-decode-multiple-times/36799/2) link does to the most part solve it.

The solution I used in the end was to check the status code of my data task before anything else. My server side code was configured such that the status code would be 200 for when the first JSON was sent, and 500 if the second JSON was sent. This meant I could simply decode the second JSON before if the status code showed that it would be sent.

Thanks for your help